# Get NSMutableDictionary from Singleton?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, singleton

I created a singleton class in order to share an object inside my program. Here's the code:

SelectedRow.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TableEntry.h"

@interface SelectedRow : NSObject {
    TableEntry *rowValue;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) TableEntry *rowValue;

+ (id)sharedManager;
- (void)setVariable:(TableEntry*)value;

@end
```

and SelectedRow.m

```
#import "SelectedRow.h"
#import "TableEntry.h"

@implementation SelectedRow

@synthesize rowValue;

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static SelectedRow *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        rowValue = [[TableEntry alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setVariable:(TableEntry*)value {
    rowValue = value;
}

@end
```

while TableEntry.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableEntry : NSObject {
@private
    NSString *videoId;
    NSString *videoCategory;
    NSString *videoTitle;
    NSString *videoDescription;
    NSDate *videoDate;
    NSMutableArray *videoRelatedVideos;
    NSDictionary *videoAdditionalInformation;
    NSString *videoAccessControl;
    NSArray *videoFields;
    NSMutableDictionary *days;
    NSMutableDictionary *views;
    NSMutableDictionary *watchtime;
    NSMutableDictionary *subscribers;
    NSMutableDictionary *shares;
}

@property (copy) NSString *videoId;
@property (copy) NSString *videoCategory;
@property (copy) NSString *videoTitle;
@property (copy) NSString *videoDescription;
@property (copy) NSMutableArray *videoRelatedVideos;
@property (copy) NSDictionary *videoAdditionalInformation;
@property (copy) NSArray *videoFields;
@property (copy) NSString *videoAccessControl;
@property (copy) NSDate *videoDate;
@property (copy) NSMutableDictionary *days;
@property (copy) NSMutableDictionary *views;
@property (copy) NSMutableDictionary *subscribers;
@property (copy) NSMutableDictionary *shares;
@property (copy) NSMutableDictionary *watchtime;

- (id)setId:(NSString*)Id setCategory:(NSString*)Category setDate:(NSDate*)date setTitle:(NSString*)title setDescription:(NSString*)description setRelatedVideos:(NSMutableArray*)relatedVideos setAdditionalInformation:(NSDictionary*)additionalInformation setAccessControl:(NSString*)accessControl setFields:(NSArray*)fields setDays:(NSMutableDictionary*)days setViews:(NSMutableDictionary*)views setSubscribers:(NSMutableDictionary*)subscribers setShares:(NSMutableDictionary*)shares setWatchtime:(NSMutableDictionary*)watchtime;

- (NSString*)extractId;
- (NSString*)extractCategory;
- (NSString*)extractTitle;
- (NSString*)extractDescription;
- (NSMutableArray*)extractRelatedVideos;
- (NSDictionary*)extractAdditionalInformationVideos;
- (NSDictionary*)extractAccessControlVideos;
- (NSArray*)extractFields;
- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractDays;
- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractViews;
- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractSubscribers;
- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractShares;
- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractWatchtime;

@end
```

and TableEntry.m

```
- (id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        videoId = @"9bZkp7q19f0";
        videoCategory = @"Music";
        videoTitle = @"Demo Title";
        videoDescription = @"Demo description";
        videoDate = [NSDate date];
        videoAdditionalInformation = [NSDictionary alloc];
        videoRelatedVideos = [NSMutableArray alloc];
        videoAccessControl = @"demo accesControl";
        videoFields = [NSArray alloc];
        days = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
        views = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
        shares = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
        subscribers = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
        watchtime = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)setId:(NSString*)Id setCategory:(NSString*)Category setDate:(NSDate*)date setTitle:(NSString*)title setDescription:(NSString*)description setRelatedVideos:(NSMutableArray*)relatedVideos setAdditionalInformation:(NSDictionary*)additionalInformation setAccessControl:(NSString*)accessControl setFields:(NSArray*)fields  setDays:(NSMutableDictionary*)Days setViews:(NSMutableDictionary*)Views setSubscribers:(NSMutableDictionary*)Subscribers setShares:(NSMutableDictionary*)Shares setWatchtime:(NSMutableDictionary*)Watchtime {
    videoId = Id;
    videoCategory = Category;
    videoDate = date;
    videoTitle = title;
    videoDescription = description;
    videoRelatedVideos = relatedVideos;
    videoAccessControl = accessControl;
    videoAdditionalInformation = additionalInformation;
    videoFields = fields;
    days = Days;
    views = Views;
    subscribers = Subscribers;
    watchtime = Watchtime;
    shares = Shares;

    return self;
}

- (NSString*)extractId {
    return self.videoId;
}

- (NSString*)extractCategory{
    return self.videoCategory;
}

- (NSString*)extractTitle{
    return self.videoTitle;
}

- (NSString*)extractDescription{
    return self.videoDescription;
}

- (NSMutableArray*)extractRelatedVideos{
    return self.videoRelatedVideos;
}

- (NSString*)extractAccessControlVideos{
    return self.videoAccessControl;
}

- (NSDictionary*)extractAdditionalInformationVideos{
    return self.videoAdditionalInformation;
}

- (NSArray*)extractFields{
    return self.videoFields;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractDays{
    return self.days;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractSubscribers{
    return self.subscribers;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractWatchtime{
    return self.watchtime;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractShares{
    return self.shares;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*)extractViews{
    return self.views;
}

@end
```

I can extract any values from the singleton with:

```
SelectedRow *selectedRow = [SelectedRow sharedManager];
NSString *videoID = [selectedRow.rowValue extractId];
```

the problem arises with any NSMutableDictionary. If I try:

```
SelectedRow *selectedRow = [SelectedRow sharedManager];
NSMutableDictionary *days = [selectedRow.rowValue extractDays];
```

or with any other NSMutableDictionary I get this error:

```
[NSMutableDictionary count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable dictionary object
```

what I'm I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: That is a lot of code to read through for something which is most likely a pretty simple problem. Any chance you could reduce the code to a few relevant lines, that can be compiled and executed as a stand-alone example?

Comment: Use [NSMutableDictionary new] instead of [NSMutableDictionary alloc], same thing for NSArrays and NSDictionaries. (BTW, whats the point of allocating immutable empty NSArrays and NSDictionaries? Either create their mutable counterparts (NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary), or assign them when needed.

Comment: Yup, always call `init...` right after every `alloc`. And to make a property of a mutable class `copy` is almost never what you want, make it strong instead! Otherwise you will always get a (immutable) copy of your ivar!

Comment: May I suggest to use NSLog(@"Label: %@",NSObjectToLog);  in critical points in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[NSMutableDictionary alloc]` call allocates the space for `NSMutableDictionary`, but it does not initialize it.

Replace it with `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` to fix the problem. Same goes for your `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` objects (replace them with `[NSMutable array]` and `[NSMutableArray array]`).

The `videoAdditionalInformation` of type `NSDictionary` should be initialized to `nil`, though, because `NSDictionary` objects are immutable. If you are planning to set it to some dictionary later on, you might as well keep it `nil` on initialization.

In addition, you should reconsider the use of `copy`: it makes sense for `NSString` objects, but it hardly makes sense on `NSMutableDictionary` objects.

Comment: Thanks, with your solution I get no more error. Unfortunately when I try to extract the value of one of those NSMutableDicitonaries I got a NULL :(

Comment: @phcaze I think you have to change more of your code. Read HAS and Tamás' comments?

Comment: @DigiMonk Not necessarily - calling `dictionary` instead of `new` is perfectly fine. With ARC it is a matter of preference, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  … but what about that "copy"? (HAS' comment)

Comment: I changed from 'copy' to 'strong' but still they are NULL when I print them. Sorry but I'm new to Objective-C.

Comment: @phcaze ok, txs for the heads up

Comment: My god.. I forgot to add the value to the singleton.. I was sure I did it but maybe it was in another version of the program.. So it WORKS! Thanks all